# googlemaps shows wrong location

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, google-maps

I obtained a key and inserted it into my code(asp.net) . The google map however shows the default location of the tutorial example Iam using although I inserted a new address in the code , please see below

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        marker: true
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: " 7 sunnyside sands , Pretoria, South Africa"
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code:

I have Changed:

```
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        marker: true
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: " 7 sunnyside sands , Pretoria, South Africa"
    });
    marker.setMap(map);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The proble is you change the ***title*** but this is not what change what is showed or where the marker is positioned.

In order to change the position you want to, you have to set the coordinates as showed in the following example (look at `myLatlng` variable):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            // Are these coordinates that has to be changed in order to change what it is showed and the marker position
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.755372, 28.212204);
            // before you had this. 
            //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)

            var mapOptions = {
                center: myLatlng,
                zoom: 14,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                marker: true
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(evt) {
                console.log(evt.latLng);
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: "This is the title and don't have any effect in the address showed: 7 sunnyside sands , Pretoria, South Africa"
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to use human readable address for show markers an so on you have to read about [DirectionService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsService)

You have an exameple about that [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple)

Comment: Your welcome. If this answer work for you please mark it as answered.
I recommend you tou read this too (you will earn a badge): http://stackoverflow.com/tour